# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke Error on Face Recognition code using Emgucv C#

Tags: invoke, cascade, face-detection, face-recognition

I was trying to run the codes i have got from codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real-ti .The code build fine but during runtime that it is throwing Emgu.CV.CvInvoke Error. And the code stops at the point where i initialize HaarCascade classifier.I did all configurations fine according to the tuitorials given here http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/announcements/-level-0-emgucv-installation-guide-for-64-bit-windows-users and i have tried other sample code including face detection code.They all work fine. 
!C:\Users\sizusuzu\Desktop\Capture.PNG!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you problem lies as per the comments in this link http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2910
I had same problem after compiling and building installer then running installer on different machine. You really need the OpenCV references as per the link...hope that helps